# Handling multiple formats: Convert to datetime (MM:DD:YYYY)

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert a column having values like May 24, 1960, Mar. 1, 1990, Aug. 22, 1981 and May 1, 1953 into Date (MM:DD:YYYY).

Notice some have '.' between month and date and some don't.

```
df['Customer DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Customer DOB'], format='%b.%d,%Y').dt.strftime('%m:%d:%Y')
```

Im getting error "time data "May 24, 1960" doesn't match format "%b. %d, %Y"," which makes sense as the code only handles cases with '.'.How do I account for both these cases?

Comment: Your question should not have been closed.  None of the answers on the referenced previous question put the date into your desired format.  This can be done using pandas.to_datetime and then manipulating the format of the timestamp object.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['Customer DOB'], format='mixed')` will parse these strings correctly.